# Why are Neural Networks Needed with Word Embeddings?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, word-embedding, cosine-similarity

Why do we need a neural network to do text classification when we vectorize documents with word embeddings? If word embeddings capture the meaning of words/documents, then why can't we just use cosine similarity to see which previously labeled documents a new document is closest to, and based off that, make a classification decision?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a stackoverflow answer, but I'll try to answer.

The texts need to be represented as numbers before we can do anything with them.

You suggest using cosine similarity - good, but what values are you going to compare with each other?

Previous approaches used simply counts (countvectorizer) or ratios (tf-idf) of tokens. Now we use embeddings, because they provide more information about the tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To answer your question, why couldn't we just compare a vector of an unknown document with vector(s) of known documents and see which vector(s) is/are closest? For this, we would just use cosine similarity.

Comment: Yes... but how would you obtain this vector? What would the values of this vector be based on? If not counts, ratios and embeddings, then how do you plan to convert the text into the vectors?

Comment: I understand why we need a neural network for vectorizing words (e.g., Word2Vec), but am confused on why we need to then plug these vectors into a neural network to classify them, instead of just using cosine similarity.

Comment: Ah, you meant cosine similarity vs neural net? These are simply different methods with the same goal. You can try both of them and compare the performance. I think that in most cases neural nets will be better than cosine similarity.

Comment: Yes, thanks! So do neural nets perform better because they can build more complex mathematical relationships? If so, is there a way to visualize these relationships? I think cosine similarity is pretty easy to do so graphically, but I can't wrap my head around vector transformations of neural nets.

Comment: Yes, neural nets work better because they have complex non-linear relationships between their layers. I don't there is any good way to visualize them.

Answer (score 1):

Because neural networks give better results than word embeddings in general.

Many text classification problems can be addressed just by using word embeddings. However, word embeddings tend to present some problems, e.g.:
they are not contextual and, therefore, for a specific word you always use the same vector. Nevertheless, in actual language, the same surface form can carry entirely different meanings, e.g. pupil of the eye vs. pupil as a student.

Of course, if your experiments on a specific problem don't show better results for neural networks than for word embeddings, you should probably opt for the simplest approach. However, that's not usually the case. You can check this at the ["text classification" category](https://paperswithcode.com/task/text-classification) of [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/) and see that the state of the art approaches are neural networks.

Comment: Thanks! I am just confused on why we need to use neural networks for text classification and why we can't just use cosine similarity with something like Word2Vec, as won't that carry contextual meaning?

Comment: The decision to use one method or the other depends on many things, but neural networks just give better results. Using word embeddings we are just obtaining a generic representation in an unsupervised way and then we reuse it for a specific supervised learning setup. With neural networks, we use representations that are learned specifically for the downstream problem we need to solve.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So is it just that neural nets are able to learn more complex transformations? If so, would there be any way to sort of visualize these graphically? Cosine similarity isn't too hard, but I can't wrap my head around the transformations a neural net would make from vector to vector.

Comment: The vector representations of neural networks have very high dimensionality. You can try dimensionality reduction techniques like [UMAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but these won't help you understand the representations. Neural networks are deemed [black boxes](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/22338/14675) because they are trained end-to-end and what they learn to achieve their training objective is not really directly understandable by a human. For transformers, I suggest you take a look at [this article](https://aclanthology.org/N19-1112/) to get an idea.